# Как пишется «конёк-горбунок» из песни исп. Боярского?

Tags: орфография

Песня называется «Сивка-бурка».

> Эй, конёк мой горбунок! Сивка-бурка, где ты?

> Эй, конёк-, мой, -горбунок! Сивка-бурка, где ты?

Comment: Котик, ты определись, в песнИ или в песнЕ, а то нацарапал лапкой ни то ни сё.

Comment: https://learnsongs.ru/song/mihail-boyarskii-sivka-burka-91677?ysclid=lq9vngipef647136854

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Боярского:

Эй, ***конёк мой горбунок***! Сивка-бурка, где ты?

Еще вариант: Эй, ***конёк мой Горбунок!***

Это **сложное обращение**, включающее притяжательное местоимение ***мой*** и два обращения: ***конек*** и ***горбунок***.

Имя конька  — ***Горбунок***, но его называют по-разному: конек, конек-горбунок (нариц.), Конек-Горбунок (собств.) и т.д.

О написании **сложных обращений** рассказано **в правилах [Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=126#pp126)** Например: *Что вы такой герцогиней смотрите, **красавица вы моя**?* (Остр.);